# asymptotic decreasing function

Tags: functions, asymptotics, special-functions

I'm currently working on my university thesis, I'm trying to model a particular behavior but I can't think of the right function that works for me.

I'm looking for:

1. Decreasing function
2. $f(0) = 1$
3. $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0.1$
4. $a\cdot f(a) = b\cdot f(b) - c\cdot f(c)$ s.t. $a=b-c$ for every $a,b,c$

I can easily go through features 1, 2 and 3 but I can't find anything suitable with number 4. 
Any help?

edit: I can also solve property number 4 with integrals, i.e. $\int f(6) = \int f(4) + \int f(2)$

Comment: Why property 4? What's special about it for your application?

Comment: I need there to be no difference between choosing x values together or separately. For example, there must be no difference between having $6 * f(6)$ or $2*f(2) + 4*f(4)$. 

I could also solve the problem with integrals, i.e. $\int f(6) = \int f(4) + \int f(2)$

Comment: $f(6)$ is a number. $\int f(6)$ is just $f(6)x+C$ for an undetermined constant $C$. I don't understand your $\int f(6)=\int f(4)+\int f(2)$.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to find a function with ∫(a)=∫(b)+∫(c) for every a,b,c with $a=b-c$ ?

Comment: That's not going to fly. If $a f(a) + b f(b) = (a + b) f(a + b)$, then $a = 1, \,b = 1$ gives $2 f(1) = 2 f(2)$, after which $a = 2, \,b = 1$  gives $3 f(1) = 3 f(3)$, and so on. Maybe your integral form means something different (what function are you integrating and over what interval)?